# Extract AAC audio properties using Python?

Tags: python, aac

What's the easiest Python library to use to extract properties from an AAC audio file (.m4a)?

Specifically, I'd like to extract the following properties:

- Sample rate
- Channel count (mono or stereo)
- Length (in seconds)

Answer (score 1):

Try the [AudioFile](http://audiotools.sourceforge.net/programming/audiotools.html#audiofile-objects) class in [Audio Tools](http://audiotools.sourceforge.net/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command exiftool. Of course, if you're using linux. This command shows all the properties of audio files, video and pictures. Exiftool installed, simply use the command:

exiftoll your_file_name.extension

eg
exiftoll music.mp3